# Redirect user after login when using openID_connect module.

Tags: 8, users, redirection

I have a Drupal 8 site that is utilizing the openID Connect module that users use to login to the site. I am also using the login destination module to set a specific page that the user is redirected to after login. The login destination module redirects correctly when a user logs in using the default Drupal login (this will not be available on the production site) or through a one time login link. However when using the openID to login, after a successful login the user is brought to their user profile page instead of the page specified in the login destination module. Anyone have any experience on how to redirect to a specific page after logging in using openID?